# Highcharts export module: Multiple Phantom JS instance in jBoss

Tags: jboss, phantomjs, highcharts

I am using Highcharts export module with the export module war file deployed in the jBoss app server.

Everytime I shutdown my jBOss i noticed there will be plenty of the following messages:

```
(Thread-6462) Shutting down PhantomJS instance, kill process directly, Thread[Thread-6462,5,main]
 (Thread-6441) Shutting down PhantomJS instance, kill process directly, Thread[Thread-6441,5,main]
 (Thread-9092) Shutting down PhantomJS instance, kill process directly, Thread[Thread-9092,5,main]
 (Thread-6197) Shutting down PhantomJS instance, kill process directly, Thread[Thread-6197,5,main]
 (Thread-6219) Shutting down PhantomJS instance, kill process directly, Thread[Thread-6219,5,main]
 (Thread-9012) Shutting down PhantomJS instance, kill process directly, Thread[Thread-9012,5,main]
```

Did anyone have the same encounter as me? Why is phantom JS spawning so many threads in the background?

Will it impact my app server's performance?

Answer (score 0):

In your config for the export module you can set how many instances of PhantomJS to start. You will see its thread set to 6 - to match the 6 PhantomJS you see running.

We use 10 because reasons. Every time we have to kickstart the Tomcat server we are left with PhantomJS orphans. It would be nice to have Tomcat or even the WAR reset functionality kill the child spawns as well.

Comment: There were more than 40 over lines of "Shutting down PhantomJS instance" in my jBoss console log although in my property file, I only requested 5 instances of Phantom JS to be loaded. I created a class that leverage on SVGConverter to build the png, could there be something that I have done wrongly? any advice is appreciated.